# Dynamically change value of textView

Tags: android-studio-3.5

I wanted that my total payable amount will get updated after every single change in ui like selecting of checkbox will result in adding that checkbox item value to total payable amount.

[image]

Comment: if you are using firestore it has option to fetch real time data change in its firebasestore. Read firebase documentation

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs some work so the community can better help you. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give it another try.